# not able to make qtXlsxWriter

Tags: qt

I'd like to include the qt xlsx library in my project, and in order to install the libraries and so in my system I've followed the instructions explained here http://qtxlsx.debao.me/building.html

I got the error "Failed to run: perl -w C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\syncqt.pl -module QtXlsx -version 0.3.0 -outdir ..." when I try to make the project. I guess Perl is correctly installed in my machine (when I tip the cmd line perl -v I get v5.12.3)  What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1 - install perl => https://www.perl.org/
2 - after that reload your machin.
3 - if you have a antivirus disable it before buildin (somme antivirus take perl as maleware like AVG in my case).
4 - run the Qt cmd 
5 - cd path/to/qrxlsxwriter
6 - run qmake
7 - mingw32-make
8 - mingw32-make install 
for more informations go to this site http://qtxlsx.debao.me/building.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a typo in the project path :-P